# Unicode display in Android TextView

Tags: android, unicode

Using typeface with appropriate TTF file enables to display Unicode characters in Android. 
How can we get the mapping of the characters corresponding to the TTF file?

Comment: What do you mean with "mapping of characters corresponding to ttf file"? Please explain your problem further.

Answer (score 2):

The ttf file needs to include these characters. You should be able to use any unicode in for example the strings.xml. If the character does not appear, then the font does not support the character.

Comment: how can we get the unicode of the font let say I have a string in edittext which is displayed in karate.ttf fontface, i want to retrieve its unicode value, if i do edittext.getText() i only get the text not the unicode set to the edittext,how can we do that? Please help .